# bash преобразование переменных

Tags: bash

Как преобразовать `01`, `02`, `03`... в `1`, `2`, `3`...

```
i=01

echo $i

01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если используется именно *bash*, то можно обойтись без громоздкого вызова дополнительной программы:

```
$ i=010
$ echo ${i##0}
10
```

---

неверное решение:

```
$ i=010
$ echo $((i))
8
```

Answer (score 3):

Нашел все-таки

```
i=01     
echo $i | bc

1
```

[Помог этот текст](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/abs-guide/flat/abs-book.html#UNITCONVERSION)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `printf`:

```
$ printf '%.f' 01
1
```